# how to handle http connector response code

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

Currently in mule, I have a flow process that makes an http connection to elasticsearch. We are using the scroll api and all connections are fine. I am trying to create a flow to handle the `404 status code` which would be returned in the event that the scroll_id has expired on a request. At the moment, I added code 404 to the advanced settings for `"Failure Status Code Validator"` section on the http connector. What I want to accomplish is that when 404 is returned from this particular http call (which we know is due to the scroll_id expiry), we make another http call to another gateway. So when 404, make another http call to a separate link.

Thanks in advance. I am still learning the xml code, but if you have an anypoint studio experience in the GUI that would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accomplished this by setting a `success status code validator` under the Advanced tab of the http-connector.

Before setting this value, when getting a 404, the mulesoft would raise its default exception for error code `4xx`. At the moment, I still can't figure out how to override that or set something additional, and that could be due to this particular project I am taking over. However, in the success code validator section, I set the values to `200,404` which is saying that a status code of 200 and 404 can pass to the next component in the flow. By default, if you don't set 404, again mulesoft will throw its default built in error message for status code 404. So since I am telling mulesoft to treat this as okay, I can pass to the next component in my project. At the next flow immediately after the outbound http call to an external rest service, I have a `choice-component` in place that is evaluating what the status code of the http call is. To do this, you can use this: `#[message.inboundProperties.'http.status' == '404']` which is saying, use this particular flow path if the status code is 404, else use the default path.

[image]

Comment: Another way to do this, if you're curious, is to catch the exception that is thrown from the 404 and handle it there. Whether you do that or what you've already done depends on the semantics though. Is a 404 an unexpected exception, or a cue to try something different? I think your current code relays that intention well.

Comment: @jerney, the 404 is expected here for this particular flow. We are using elasticsearch, so the 404 indicates that a particular api we are calling expired (resource no longer available), and we are expecting this to happen after a certain period of time. When I attempted to implement the exception catching, I was running into the issue of "No Listener Found for Endpoint xxx"